# How to hover over and expand dropdown menu on komoot with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, hover

My goal is to get an element within a dropdown menu that needs to be clicked in order to appear using python `selenium`. Also, it seems that before the click, hovering is necessary.
I tried to click the dropdown menu like this:

```
element = wait().until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "c-topmenu c-topmenu--create c-topmenu--userbar tw-inline-flex")))
element.click()
```

```
def wait():
    return WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
```

And tried to use hovering:

```
Hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
Hover.click().build().perform()
```

Still, I get a TimeoutException and can't figure out a solution.

The website komoot looks like this before clicking the dropdown menu:

[image: before expanding dropdown]

The website komoot looks like this after expanding it:

[image: after expanding dropdown]

Comment: can you show the event that is behind the a tag. maybe you can simply execute the javascript instead of clicking it

Comment: Let me know if my answer resolved your problem

Comment: @Prophet Thanks, yes. Initially I was looking for another element (an alternative solution to my problem) with a unique class name and I was using EC.element_to_be_clickable but still it did not work. With the other element now I forgot about the uniqueness. Thanks for pointing out that presence located is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong locator.
In case of multiple class names you should use css_selector or XPath, not by class name.
Also, here you have an unique attribute of `data-test-id`, you should use it.
Also, you should wait for element visibility or clickability, not just for element presence.
So your code could be:

```
element = wait().until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-test-id='more_menu']")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is how i was able to get this working.

after the login i grapped the wrapper element from the link with:

```
more_menu_wrapper = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-test-id='more_menu']")
```

after that i could click the desired element with:

```
more_menu_wrapper.find_element_by_tag_name("a").click()
```